# Sound: can test it but no sound on browser or VLC

Tags: audio, web-browsers, vlc

Looking for a solution for long time and did not find any one that solved my problem. Most of them refer to absolutely no sound from RPi, no sound on VLC or no sound in Chrome. Neither one works for me.

On my issue, I can open [Sound settings], choose the device (Analog Output Built-in Audio or HDMI/DisplayPort Built-in Audio) and use [Test sound] to hear "Front left" and "Front right". But when I open VLC and try to listen a MP3 file, it starts but there is no sound playing. And when browsing any site, if there is sound on it, I can not hear anything.

Even from Terminal, I can hear "Front center" after <aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav>, and with the sound the answer is "Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono". But no sound if try command line for VLC.

I am not sure, but I think that is something related with which codecs are enabled. I have:

- H264: H264=enabled
- MPG2: MPG2=disabled
- WVC1: WVC1=disabled
- MPG4: MPG4=disabled
- MJPG: MJPG=enabled
- WMV9: WMV9=disabled

Any suggestion I will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

...

- RPi 4B Rev 1.5 4GB (BCM2835)
- Debian GNU/Linux 11 bullseye (aarch64)
- Cinnamon v4.8.6
- Kernel 6.1.21-v8+

Comment: is the vilume control turned  up?

Comment: Certainly it is up. As I wrote, I can test and ear. But playing from VLC has no sound. That is the issue.